# How to encrypt specific JSON fields in python with reasonable performance

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, regex, encryption

I want to encrypt only the sensitive information inside a JSON file, let's say that the file look like this:

```json
{
  "entities": [
     {
       "name": "john doe",
       "personalInformation" : {
                "email": "john.doe@email.com",
                "password": "sensitiveinformation123@"
        }
     }
    , ...
  ]
}
```

What i want to do is to encrypt ONLY the sensitive fields of the file, so for example, if i say that the fields `email` and `password` are sensitive information i will encrypt only  the value for this field and later i will decrypt everything.

The encrypted JSON should look like this:

```json
{
  "entities": [
     {
       "name": "john doe",
       "personalInformation" : {
                "email": "gAAAAABgXeNr95vq78gambIlZGabAZeQRptNqzXfS_qmNB5O6KBneARNpnqX6OP4Q0s4NeRtkQZRNQRizHKLB2Ydj5Uso-OngD4=",
                "password": "xUFGAgXeNr95vq78gambIlZGabAZeQRptNqzXfSIlZGaBneARNpnqX6OP4Q0s4NeRtkQZRNQRizHKLB2Ydj5Uso-OngD4="
        }
     }
    , ...
  ]
}
```

I've tried to use Fernet to encrypt the fields using regex, but the performance couldn't be worse, also when I try to decrypt the file I need to decrypt field by field the same way that I did to encrypt, otherwise i get the `cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken` error because the lib try to decrypt the whole file and not only there is encrypted data.

Code that I have right now:

```py
import json, html, copy
from pydash import get
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet 
import re

def encrypt_json_fields(data: str, fields: list, encryption_key: str) -> str:

    encrypted = copy.copy(data)
    pii = []
    fer = Fernet(encryption_key)

    for f in fields:
        pii += set(re.findall(r'(?<="{0}": ").*?(?=",)'.format(f),data))
    
        for value in set(pii):
        encrypted = encrypted.replace(value,(fer.encrypt(bytes(value, encoding='utf-8'))).decode('utf-8'))
    
    return encrypted
```

Is there an easy way to encrypt those specific fields? And is there a way to auto decrypt only the encrypted data or will i need to write the same function but with the reverse logic to decrypt only these fields?

Comment: 2 Questions, 1) Would it be problematic for you to read the json data and then write it back after encrypting? 2) How many entries do you have, that it becomes so slow? When I directly encrypt the personal information, it takes less than a second for ~2000 entries.

Comment: Answering your questions 1) no it won't be problematic, but the problem is not in that part 
2) it depends on the size of the object inside the entities list, I got some files with 500 records with around 40 nested properties and when I process them it takes around 7-9 seconds,  but when i got simple object with few properties I can process 1000 records in less then a second

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is solution will be fast enough, so if you could provide me with the timings on your data set, that would be appreciated.

Also I don't have your original properties, but from your example I made the assumption that your data consists only out of nested dictionaries (please provide a full example if this isn't the case).

---

### Helper files

- File `data.json`: This contains your unencrypted json data.

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "name": "john doe",
      "personalInformation": {
        "email": "john.doe@email.com",
        "password": "sensitiveinformation123@"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "jane doe",
      "personalInformation": {
        "email": "jane.doe@email.com",
        "password": "sensitiveinformation123@"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- File `settings.json`: This contains a path to your `Fernet` secret key (which should not be public) and it contains a dictionary structure that explains which fields have to be encrypted / decrypted. It can have an arbitrary number of nested dictionaries.

```
{
  "pathKey": "secret.key",
  "fields": {
    "name": false,
    "personalInformation": {
      "email": true,
      "password": true
    }
  }
}
```

- File `crypto_fernet.py`: file that contains default functions for the encryption protocol. Currently still using the `Fernet` encryption, if this is not fast enough a new file can be created with a faster encryption protocol without having to change the interface.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet


def generate_key(path='secret.key'):
    """ Generates a key and save it into a file.  """
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    with open(path, "wb") as file:
        file.write(key)
    return Fernet(key)


def load_key(path='secret.key'):
    """ Load a previously generated key. """
    with open(path, 'rb') as file:
        key = file.read()
    return Fernet(key)


def encrypt(message: str, f: Fernet):
    return f.encrypt(str(message).encode())


def decrypt(message: bytes, f: Fernet):
    return f.decrypt(message).decode()
```

---

### Solution

- Helper function to load json files:

```
def load_json(path):
    """ Loads a json file.  """
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    return data
```

- Recursive function that either encodes or decodes the fields. This is based on the `encode` variable. If this is `True` it will `encrypt` the fields, if `False` it will `decrypt` the fields.

```
def protect(data: Union[dict, str, bytes], fields: Union[dict, bool], f: Fernet, encode=True):
    if isinstance(fields, bool) and fields is True:
        return encrypt(data, f) if encode else decrypt(data, f)
    if isinstance(fields, dict):
        for key, value in fields.items():
            data[key] = protect(data[key], value, f, encode=encode)
    return data
```

The `data` and `fields` are assumed to be matching dictionaries, therefore every entry has to be the same. If this is not the case, you have to add an extra check to see if the `key` is contained in `data`. In any case use:

```
if isinstance(fields, dict):
    for key, value in fields.items():
        if key in data: # <-- add this line
            data[key] = protect(data[key], value, f, encode=encode)
```

A second condition is that all entries in the dictionaries are either strings or dictionaries. If you use lists, you have to expand this section with the following

```
if isinstance(fields, list):
    for idx in range(min(len(fields), len(data))):
        data[idx] = protect(data[idx], fields[idx], f, encode=encode)
```

- Main

```
import json
import os

from pprint import pprint
from typing import Union
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

from crypto_fernet import generate_key, load_key, encrypt, decrypt

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Load data, path to the key and the information about which fields have to be encoded or decoded.
    data = load_json('data.json')
    settings = load_json('settings.json')
    key, fields = settings['pathKey'], settings['fields']

    # Generate the Fernet encryptor
    if not os.path.exists(key):
        f = generate_key(key)
    else:
        f = load_key(key)

    # Protects / encrypt every entity with the fields that return True
    for idx, entity in enumerate(data['entities']):
        data['entities'][idx] = protect(entity, fields, f)
    pprint(data, width=100)

    # Unprotect / decrypt every entity with the fields that return True
    for idx, entity in enumerate(data['entities']):
        data['entities'][idx] = protect(entity, fields, f, encode=False)
    pprint(data, width=100)
```

#### Output

```
{'entities': [{'name': 'john doe',
               'personalInformation': {'email': b'gAAAAABgXmBIwmGZsLZvHAAKhU3rZoGyIg9isfDVv0dDr_5suyTabE-e1PjQu4Bv5OIgu4SuZa11xuYixAQRTxk66jV3IceLmOLyUVRRv-_22ue7mLYHfTQ=',
                                       'password': b'gAAAAABgXmBIwz02Edo6TYRrTGAPtTFxznpOEi3H5EjyLcwX5vRE9FJ2Af1WJNEq7tVf1hBWsKmA4aThJSUQJS8NuX7_oAVjR9FjqPfh34mKuTfb6pe2TSQ='}},
              {'name': 'jane doe',
               'personalInformation': {'email': b'gAAAAABgXmBIAnyAZr9UiRDArmqSfuI13_HoYKzChbf5WfejGbV7ZHZcAoNBQgyck-GTI6IXXCaBDTZDXg_RkFsDOZCqPiFuf90bC7OStzwXLzTgm0SVVNM=',
                                       'password': b'gAAAAABgXmBILH5mJ2Eectc9u3DUyxQw1RMsH3lB3jPHLADpXNZRWBoU9FdegJiz_fa3YpjsBYsZmbgWPkmsDOJ0JFTKCTS4bncMd8rUN0t6-Zatxy_UOC8='}}]}
```

```
{'entities': [{'name': 'john doe',
               'personalInformation': {'email': 'john.doe@email.com',
                                       'password': 'sensitiveinformation123@'}},
              {'name': 'jane doe',
               'personalInformation': {'email': 'jane.doe@email.com',
                                       'password': 'sensitiveinformation123@'}}]}
```

#### Advantages

- The main advantage is that you can now decrypt a single entry without having to decrypt everything.
- You can control the fields that you want to encode using a boolean mask. Extra note on this, it is enough for your `settings.json` to only include the variables that have to be encoded, since all values that are `false` will be ignored anyways. Hence `"name": false` is not necessary.

#### Test

I increased the number of nested fields to around 20, and tested it for 2000 records (encoding and decoding). This takes around 5 seconds for me. Which would mean that it should be roughly a second on your data set (twice the number of fields, but a quarter of the data and only requires encoding.)